# Read excel file from sharepoint document library in office 365 programmatically

Tags: office-365, excel, file

I have one excel file uploaded in document library of office 365 site.I want to read this excel file using c# as we read in farm solution using following code.

```
            using (SPSite site = new SPSite("siteurl"))
            {
                using (SPWeb web = site.RootWeb)
                {
                    SPFile file = web.Folders["Shared Documents"].Files["test.xlsx"];
                    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(file.OpenBinaryStream());
                    contents = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
```

But this code is not working in sandbox solution. It will give error for OpenBinaryStream function during build step.Actually I want to create sharepoint list from excel file in office 365 programmatically. I have also tried manual step from this link http://blog.blksthl.com/2014/01/15/office-365-guide-series-create-a-new-list-from-an-excel-spreadsheet/ but when i click on import button it gives this error : An unexpected error has occurred.(-2147221005).

Comment: I know SPFile.OpenBinaryStream() is not available in Sandboxed solutions in 2010, so I don't think it'll work with 2013.  As for the app in your link, you'll have to contact the developer.